# Putting a line feed in a string built in an excel formula in a data label

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to construct a data label in an excel chart using a formula building the string from two cells with a line break between them.

This would work in a cell formula:

```
=A1 & CHAR(10) & B1
```

and this would work in VBA

```
=A1 & Chr(10) & B1
```

as in this post: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40644 but neither of these approaches works inside a data label. Any ideas?

Comment: In order for this to work in cells Word Wrap needs to be enabled. Is this an option in the data label?

Comment: No, but if I reference a cell with a line break then it seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I got it working.

Step 1: create a new column with wordwrap enabled with the formula `=A1 & CHAR(10) & B1` in cell `C1` and drag down as appropriate

Step 2: Run the following VBA code to set each data label to point to the correct cell

```
Sub SetDataLabels()

    Dim ChartName As String
    ChartName = "My Chart's Name"

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ChartName).Chart

        Dim Series As Integer
        Series = 4

        With .SeriesCollection(Series)

            Dim currentPoint As Integer

            For currentPoint = 1 To .Points.Count

                .Points(currentPoint).DataLabel.Text = Range("C" & currentPoint).Text

            Next currentPoint
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you can use this:

```
Dim str as String

str = Range("A").Value & vbCrlf & Range("B").Value
```

vbCrlf will give you line break...

Comment: `=A1 & CHAR(10) & B1` works too, if you do as Brad says and set the cell to use word wrap. You cannot set this up inside of the dataseries definition. It has to be referenced to a cell or setup with vba.

Comment: =A1 & Chr(10) & B1 works perfectly in VBA as well as I mentioned in my question. Solving this in VBA is not the problem but thanks anyway. Also vbNewLine works which is probably the most readable choice if you use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in VBA:

```
Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "a" & vbCr & "b"
```

And as said, this works with a formula:

```
=DATASERIES(Sheet1!$E$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4,1)

E1 = "a" & CHAR(10) & "b"
```

E1 has to have word wrap set.

DATASERIES is what you see in the formula edit section, when you have selected your series.

Comment: The DATASERIES part is unnecessary, all I needed was to put the line break in a cell and then make the data label reference that cell. So =A1&CHAR(10)&B1 in a word wrapped cell (say C1) and then in the data label just =C1 works. I'm not sure if this is what you were saying in your answer but I'm going to mark it as correct, perhaps you can edit it to reflect this comment.

Comment: OK I see the advantage of setting it with that DATASERIES formula but it gives me an error. I'm using excel 2012. If I click on a series the formula I get is this: =SERIES("Floating Rate Notes",NSS!$I$35:$I$85,NSS!$L$35:$L$85,5) I have tried adding the data label range as a parameter in a few places but nothing works, and also I tried changing SERIES to DATASERIES but also no good. Any ideas?

Comment: My Example was on excel2007, and yes, it ment, what you described in your comment. I just used the DATASERIES formula instead of the corresponding dialog. Based on what you wrote, I would have changed it to e.g. `=SERIES(NSS!$I$34,NSS!$I$35:$I$85,NSS!$L$35:$L$85,5)` but I cannot test that.

Comment: Wait but then where do you put the series name which is the first parameter in my SERIES() function? And also if you are just referencing one single cell, then you only get one datalabel no? I need all of points to have labels referencing different cells, so replace NSS!$I$34 with a range. But looking at your formula, it seems like you are trying to get the linebreak in the series name, not a datalable. I have solved this with VBA, but if there is a way to not I'm keen to hear it.

Comment: Ah, ok, yeah, then here was a misunderstanding - I would not know of any way to individually assign values to data-lables without VBA. Somehow I was under the strong impression you ment series-label.

Comment: Cool no worries, you can do it manually by clicking on the data lables them selves twice and then typing in the formula bar but I had 50 points hence the VBA. I'll post my VBA code for posterity.